# How to disable google fonts on administrative theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I want my Google fonts to show up in front end, but when enabled they also change in back end....(7 theme)...

How do I make them ONLY show up on front end Boostrap them but NOT in back end theme?

There should be a setting...but I can't find it! I am using the [@font-your-face](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontyourface) module.

Comment: The answer is going to depend on how you have your Google Font installed on your site. How are you enabling the font?

Comment: I'm using "@font-your-face provider with Google fonts. - Version: 7.x-2.8" this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/fontyourface